# Liferay ckeditor upgrade

Tags: ckeditor, liferay-6

I'm working with Liferay version 6.1.20 but sadly in this version the ckeditor 4.0 isn't implemented yet.

Is there a way to manualy upgrade CKEditor? or is it a job that i shouldn't start because it's to much work?

I would like to manualy update the CKEditor because the plugin that i'm hooking on isn't compatible with older versions of CKEditor.

I have been looking around on the web. But there isn't any information present as far as i know. I would be nice to know if it's word trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that Replacing the ckeditor.js file and adding all the new required files is the first step of replacing the ckeditor. Besides that it's important to change the CKeconfig.jsp and remove all the old configurations. Toolbar settings can be made. These don't seem to cause any problems.

If your working with the .on method please notice that the contentDom event is fired 2 times. Once on loaded and once when the editor is ready. I checked editor.status === "ready" to prevent this. Because it is attaching the listeners when it's not ready.. Because of this the won't work.

=== Edit ===

Still having problems. But now with the save as draft action. It's saving the data but without the Html changes i have made.. I'm making span's with special attributes. but the editor won't save them..

== Edit 2 == 
The problem was a missing CKEDITOR config tag. config.allowedContent = true; (See edit for the problem)

Answer (score 0):

Ckeditor 4.0 is included in the trunk (6.2 M4) (this can be seen in the post from Juan Fernández in the [liferay forum](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/18520875). Don't know if it will be part of 6.1 GA3 due shortly. I'm not sure how complex it is to upgrade CKEditor. You may want to see the github pull request mentioned in Juan's post.

Comment: Tanks for the reply, but i couldn't miss that forum post.. it is the only thing returned when searching on google. The thing is that with the update about 85 files are changed, at least that was with a pull request that i have seen for updating CKEditor. And i don't have enough experience with Liferay to make a separation of what is important and what isn't.